External Hard drive mount, and Make directory
cloud@cloud-System-Product-Name:~$ cd /media/

cloud@cloud-System-Product-Name:/media$ ls 

cloud

cloud@cloud-System-Product-Name:/media$ cd /media/cloud/

cloud@cloud-System-Product-Name:/media/cloud$ ls
'6TB Expansion'

cloud@cloud-System-Product-Name:/media/cloud$ cd /media/cloud/6TB Expansion/

bash: cd: too many arguments

cloud@cloud-System-Product-Name:/media/cloud$ 

I am fairly new to Ubuntu/Linux. I am trying to access this Mounted 6Tb Expansion, so I can install a directory, and files there. It is saying bash: cd: too many arguments. what is the Process of accessing this expansion.enter image description here

It has a space.  You need to quote it for cd, just like you did with the ls.
Recommend to avoid making directories with spaces, it will make your life easier when scripting.  Use dashes and underscores if possible.

Changing the name to6TB has fixed my issue, thank you

That helped thanks for the information, removing the spaces did the trick.
